# How to handle If statement in useEffect initial rendering

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ErrorLabel) return;
    dispatch(setPinnedError(ErrorLabel));
  }, []);
```

I want only one time dispatch in this code, so i use empty **dependency array** in useEffect.
But ErrorLabel first value is always undefined, so i use if statement. Value comes in after a few seconds...
Because of first value of ErrorLabel i can't **dispatch** value...
I want to write code like if ErrorLabel is undefined -> then wait and when a value comes in execute dispatch.

Comment: add `dispatch` into dependency array, its undefined because store is not initialized yet. It will rerun after initialization of store

Comment: Did you read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect? `useEffect(() => { /**/ }, [ErrorLabel])`

Comment: if i add [ErrorLabel] because of infinite loop problem, i can't use that solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is instead of using `useEffect` , create a new function and put the code in there. And call it in the `return`.

```
const App = () => {

  const nameOfFunc = () => {
    if (!ErrorLabel) return;
    dispatch(setPinnedError(ErrorLabel));
  }

  return (
    {nameOfFunc()}
  )
}
```

`nameOfFunc` will only be called when the page starts `rendering` and up to that point the value of `ErrorLabel` won't be `undefined`.